# php grouping a while loop

Tags: php, loops, dreamweaver

I see from reading other posts on this site, there a similar solutions to what I am trying to do, but as I'm building in Dreamweaver, some of the syntax is different and I'm not sure what parts I need.

I think there's an If {} statment to add, just not sure where...

So I have a page for selecting a from a list of cruise holidays, the user chooses where they would like to go from a drop down menu, that then shows the cruises going to that destination. Easy. Next, they can choose when they would like to travel, narrowing the search result down with a jump menu to a particular month

So my first set of records are all the cruises going to say the Caribbean.

There are four, two in April 2012 and two in May 2012.

So I've got all four showing in my list, but now I want the user to pick a month, and by populating the jump menu with the destination-filtered recordset, I get four choices

April 2012
April 2012
May 2012
May 2012

What I actually want is

April 2012
May 2012

If I group the records by month in the MySQL query, I don't get all four cruises in the destination list, which we want.

Here's the code for the Month selector menu

```
<select name="jumpMenu2" id="jumpMenu2" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
        <option value="">Select a date</option>
        <?php do { ?>

<option value="chooseacruise.php?destination=<?php echo    urlencode($row_cruises['destination']);?>&<?php echo $row_cruises['departs']?>"><?php echo  date('F Y', strtotime($row_cruises['departs'])); ?></option>

<?php } while ($row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises));
                $rows = mysql_num_rows($cruises);
                if($rows > 0) {
                mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
            $row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises);
              }
            ?>
      </select>
```

The while loop is Dreamweaver's standard loop to populate the menu. What I want to is write the month, then at the next row, if the month is the same, ignore it.

Thanks in advance

Rich :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with Dreamweaver. The syntax is the same. Here is a simple solution for you:

```
<select name="jumpMenu2" id="jumpMenu2" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option value="">Select a date</option>
    <?php
        $month = ''; 
        while ($row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises)) { 
            if ($row_cruises['departs'] != $month) {
                $month = $row_cruises['departs'];
                ?>
                <option value="chooseacruise.php?destination=<?php echo    urlencode($row_cruises['destination']);?>&<?php echo $row_cruises['departs']?>"><?php echo  date('F Y', strtotime($row_cruises['departs'])); ?></option>
            <?php } ;
        }

        if(mysql_num_rows($cruises) > 0) {
            mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
            $row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises);
        }
    ?>
  </select>
```

Please be aware that you have to order the sql query by departs.

Comment: this one still produces the correct list of destinations, but then either no months, or a list of months short of one. E.g. I have four cruises in December, they all show, but in the month selector only three Decembers, so getting there I think...

Comment: I think I know why I am getting an odd result too, the departs field is a datetime string, like this 2012-01-05 14:30. So I guess I need to only get the month and year for the comparison...

Comment: Update to the above, which now works except when there is only one destination record, in which case there is no month to choose...       if (date('F Y', strtotime($row_cruises['departs'])) != $month) {
                $month = date('F Y', strtotime($row_cruises['departs']));
                ?>

Comment: try to add `mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);` before the while loop.